# Passing variable in URL using Invoke-WebRequest (JSON - Powershell)

Tags: json, bash, powershell

Need your help on this. I cannot get the right way of passing the variable to the URL. I am receiving errors.

```
**$SRnumber** = Read-Host "Enter SR Number"
    #144152
    $requestDescr = 
      Invoke-WebRequest 'https://test.com/api/v3/requests/**$SRnumber**?TECHNICIAN_KEY=ABCDEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' |
       ConvertFrom-Json  |
        Select -expand request
```

Error im receiving is below,

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"response_status":{"status_code":4000,"messages":[{"status_code":4007,"type":
"failed"}],"status":"failed"}}
At line:4 char:3
```

Answer (score 1):

To use interpolated strings in powershell, you need to use double-quotes:

```bsh
$SRnumber = Read-Host "Enter SR Number"
#144152
$requestDescr = Invoke-WebRequest "https://test.com/api/v3/requests/$SRnumber?TECHNICIAN_KEY=ABCDEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" |
    ConvertFrom-Json | Select -expand request
```